# Filter WebCollection using a List of Urls

Tags: 2013, development, filter, client-object-model, query

I have a List that holds the URLs of the Subsites I want to retrieve. I need to use that as a filter (optimize the query) so when I query the SharePoint it only returns the webs I want to work with. I'm using CSOM and I was trying this query:

```
    List<string> listOfSites = new List<string>(); // lets consider this has been populated

    var query = from webs in subsites
                where listOfSites.Contains(webs.Url)
                select webs;

   IEnumerable<Web> webz = clientContext.loadQuery(query);
```

I can't use Contains, ClientContext throws an exception when I try to use it. Do I have any alternative?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, there might be another way rather getting all webs like this.

Comment: I just don't want to get all webs when I know exactly in what webs I will work on. Basically I'll delete all webs whose URLs are contained on that List.

Comment: If you have the list of URL's then you can do a foreach and delete those. I think that is the best option.